# Unable to select Gmail Important in Smart Mailbox

Tags: mail.app, gmail

I have two Google email accounts -- one gmail.com and other managed by university.

I want to have a smart mailbox that shows important emails from both accounts.

But I am unable to do so.

The important folder from gmail.com gets unselected when I click ok and reopen next time.

I run macOS Catalina 10.15.4, not sure whether its specific to my computer because of some corrupt configuration. Appreciate any thoughts on fixing this.

[image: smart mailbox window]